# ShellScriptでルート権限かどうかを調べるスクリプトを書きたいのですが、${EUID:-${UID}} = 0の解説をしていただけますか？

Tags: linux, bash, shellscript

下記のShellScriptの意味がわかりませんので、解説していただけないでしょうか？
具体的には1行目の`${EUID:-${UID}} = 0`の意味がよくわかりません…。

```
if [ ${EUID:-${UID}} = 0 ]; then
    echo 'I am root.'
fi
```

Comment: 質問への回答ではないですが、Linuxは`setuid`されたスクリプトに対し実行ユーザの切り替えを無視します。(本家stackoverflowだと次の質問参照。https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/364/allow-setuid-on-shell-scripts) 実現したいことについて問題ないでしょうか?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ${EUID:-${UID}} = 0

は変数EUIDが未定義または値が空のとき、変数UIDの値と0を比較しています。

bashの例ですがmanマニュアルに詳しい説明があります。
https://linuxjm.osdn.jp/html/GNU_bash/man1/bash.1.html

> ${parameter:-word}
> デフォルトの値を使います。 parameter が設定されていないか空文字列であれば、 word を展開したものに置換されます。そうでなければ、 parameter の値に置換されます。

Comment: ちなみに`dash`(Ubuntu系のデフォルトの`sh`)には`$EUID`も`$UID`も存在しないので、これで現在の`$USER`を確認する場合はshebangを`#!/bin/bash`にする必要があります。

Comment: $EUIDも$UIDも存在しないのであれば[ $(id -r -u) = 0 ] でも良いかもしれません。 [ $(id -r -u) = 0 ] && echo root || echo not root　はdashでも動きました。